# Why I don't get the same objects when using objectWithID with CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a `NSManagedObjectContext` where two `NSManagedObject` are saved.

I'm calling a method in another thread and I need to access those two `NSManagedObject` so I created a child context like the following:

```
let childManagedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
childManagedContext.parentContext = self.managedContext
```

When I do:

```
let myNSManagedObject1 = childManagedContext.objectWithID(self.myNSManagedObject1.objectID) as! MyNSManagedObject
let myNSManagedObject2 = childManagedContext.objectWithID(self.myNSManagedObject2.objectID) as! MyNSManagedObject
```

`myNSManagedObject1` and `myNSManagedObject2` are not the same objects as `self.myNSManagedObject1` and `self.myNSManagedObject2`. Can someone explain me why?

Plus if I use `existingObjectWithID` instead of `objectWithID`, it seems I still have a fault object for my relationship in `myNSManagedObject1` and `myNSManagedObject2`:

```
relationShipObject = "<relationship fault: 0x170468a40 'relationShipObject'>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that they are the "same" in the sense that they refer to the same object in your object graph. If you compare all attributes, you will find that they are equal.

However, because they are in different contexts, they will be two separate instances of this object. So the machine address you see will be different. I hope that clears up the confusion.

As for the "fault", that only means that the underlying object (or attribute) has not yet been fetched into memory. This is simply an optimization mechanism to minimize memory footprint. If you were to log the object or attribute explicitly, it would be fetched from the store and displayed as expected. See "[Faulting and Uniquing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html)" in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html).

Comment: I thought that using `existingObjectWithID` was actually forcing the full load of those objects. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have one *object*, that is the version that's in Core Data. When you use `objectWithID:` you create an *instance* of that object. So, if you do it twice you get two instances of the same object. (Much in the same way that you can create two objects of the same class.)

Of course, if you  try to save your context, having changed one but not the other, weird things might happen.

A common pattern is where you create a new "editing" managed object context and create a new instance there. Then if the user pressed Cancel, you can just delete the context and not have to worry about rolling back any changes. I can't think where having two instances on the same context would be useful.